# Xdebug 3.0 sends stop signal to application on step over or step into

Tags: php, apache, xdebug

So for some reason, local enviroment debbuger stopped working for me.
The script runs fine if I have debugger disabled.
But once I enable debugger and hit breakpoint, the application recieves shutdown signal.
Here is the xdebug log from single run:

here are the last lines of xdebug.log

```
[22776] [Step Debug] <- step_over -i 282
[22776] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="step_over" transaction_id="282" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>

[22776] [Step Debug] <- run -i 283
[22776] Log closed at 2022-03-22 11:46:15.011006
```

And here is the php.ini xdebug config

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension="c:/wamp64new/bin/php/php7.3.33/zend_ext/php_xdebug-3.1.1-7.3-vc15-x86_64.dll"
;xdebug.mode allowed are : off develop coverage debug gcstats profile trace
xdebug.mode = debug
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_host = "localhost"
xdebug.output_dir ="c:/wamp64new/tmp"
xdebug.show_local_vars=0
xdebug.log ="c:/wamp64new/logs/xdebug.log"
xdebug.log_level =7
```

I have been bashing my head against this for few hours and was not able find even something that remotely could solve the issue.

Comment: Can you upgrade to 3.1.3? There are some related bugs fixed.

Comment: @Derick Bloody hell, that worked. Please add it as answer so I can award you and close

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Xdebug 3.1.1 has some bugs that are fixed in Xdebug [3.1.2](https://xdebug.org/updates#x_3_1_2) and [3.1.3](https://xdebug.org/updates#x_3_1_3). In this case. I would recommend to upgrade Xdebug to the latest version, which is at the time of me writing this answer: [Xdebug 3.1.3](https://xdebug.org/updates#x_3_1_2).